# how to remove duplicate emails with scripting in Zimbra

Tags: ubuntu, email, zimbra

Is there any way to delete duplicate emails from Zimbra accounts (locally hosted, licensed) with a script?

I have had to export/import thousands of emails for a user, from one Zimbra server to another. In cases where the user had folders in folders, the export/import missed chunks of emails.

To handle this, I re-imported the folder. But now I have duplicate emails (even though I had the option checked for "how to handle duplicates: ignore").

Now I am having to go folder by folder, selecting and deleting duplicates with SHIFT+DEL (so the duplicates won't go into the user's trash).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this python script, this should do the job: https://github.com/quentinsf/IMAPdedup